# Can't Register for a Developer Account

Tags: developer-program

I'm trying to create a developer account at `developer.apple.com`, but every time I click "Register", it says the server at `developercms.apple.com` couldn't be found. Is this happening to anyone else? How can I get past this?

Comment: Downvoter: Please let me know why you downvoted. I seriously don't know what to do - I can't make an account to post on Apple's developer forums, so this is the only place I knew.

Comment: What happens if you use a different browser/computer/network?

Comment: Same thing. I tried with Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, as well as both networks I have access to *and* another computer.

Comment: So it's most probably a problem on Apple's side then...

Comment: Ah, well. So it's not something I can fix?

Comment: call apple support  if your in a hurry might get fixed instantly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the Register button does nothing. I've finally got it working by filling out the information for an Apple ID that doesn't have a developer account, then clicking "Login" instead of "Register". It then takes me to a "Review Agreement" page where I can register for a developer account.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. The DNS name doesn't exist, so changing browsers is of no use.

Apple needs to either publish the domain name in DNS so that it resolves to an IP address or they need to update the HTML to use the correct name that does exist.

It appears that either Apple's DNS broke and they either haven't realised, don't care to fix it, or it is very difficult to fix and they haven't put a workaround in place (improbable IMFO).

Unless you know what the IP address should be and it's just a DNS issue, you could add a host entry as a workaround. However, if the IP address is unknown or if the server/infrastructure is down in addition to DNS then there is nothing we can do except wait for Apple and hope they fix it.